# Listing three items where the latter two are in a group. Put two "and"?

Tags: sentence-patterns, complex-sentences

I am trying to write a sentence similar to the following. This one looks dumb as there are many jargon in my original sentence. This is an example with simple wordings:

```
Our candidates include Tom, who is a boy and Betty and Mary, who are girls.
```

Clearly, Betty and Mary are in one group. However, the sentence is hard to read as there are two "and". What is the correct way to write it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptions are parenthetical and need to be set off with commas. You are missing a necessary comma after *boy*.

> Our candidates include Tom, who is a boy, and Betty and Mary, who are girls.

Here the descriptions "who is a boy" and "who are girls" are surrounded by commas. Those phrases can be omitted without changing the sense of the sentence (although that will mean that an *and* can also be removed).

Answer (score 0):

The boy Tom and the two girls Betty and Mary are our candidates.

The boy Tom, the two girls Betty and Mary are our candidates.

Our candidates are the boy Tom plus Betty and Mary, the two girls.

**Our candidates are the boy Tom plus two girls Betty together with Mary.**

Answer (score 0):

Consider

> Our candidates include Betty, Mary, who are girls, and Tom, who is a boy.
>
> or
>
> Our candidates include Betty, Mary (who are girls), and Tom (who is a boy).